# How can I get row index in google or-tools?

Tags: or-tools

I have a two-dimensional bool array, and I want to find the row index(index+1) of each column element that is not 0,If all the elements of the column are 0, the row index we get is 0. In addition, each column has at most 1 value that is not 0。How can I do it？

[image]

**The following code cannot handle the case where one column is all zeros**

```
model = cp_model.CpModel()
solver = cp_model.CpSolver()

shifts = {}
worker_shift={}


for i in range(6):
    worker_shift[(i)]=model.NewIntVar(0, 6, "worker_shift(%i)" % (i))
    for j in range(6):
        shifts[(i,j)] = model.NewBoolVar("shifts(%i,%i)" % (i,j))

for j in range(6): 
    model.Add(sum(shifts[(i,j)] for i in range(6))<=1)


for j in range(6):
    for i in range(6):
        model.Add(worker_shift[(j)]==i+1).OnlyEnforceIf(shifts[(i,j)])  

        
model.Add(shifts[(2,1)]==1)

r1= np.empty([6,6], dtype = int)
r2=np.empty([1,6], dtype = int)


status = solver.Solve(model) 
print("status:",status) 
for i in range(6):
    r2[0,i]=solver.Value(worker_shift[(i)])
    for j in range(6):
        r1[i,j]=solver.Value(shifts[(i,j)])

print(r1)    
print("----------------------")
print(r2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at one column

```
[b1..bn]
```

if we create

```
pi == n - bi * (n - i)
```

Then using `model.AddMinEquality()`, `min([pi])` computes the same think as your code.

Now let's introduce `e` a new Boolean variable.

we want

```
e <=> bool_or(pi)
```

We code it the usual way

```
for all i, pi => e  (using model.AddImplication())
bool_or([b1, ..., bn, e.Not()])  (reverse implication, if all bi are false, then e is false.
```

Now, we can use the correct min() using a new IntVar `pe[0..n]`

```
model.Add(pe = e*n)
model.AddMinEquality(target, [p1, .., pn, pe])
```

Comment: Did you perhaps meant bi instead of pi in `e <=> bool_or(pi)` and the implication part?

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @Laurent Perron,@Stradivari ！

I studied the introduction of or-tools in @Stradivari's blog(https://www.xiang.dev/cp-sat/#iff-equivalence-boolean-product), I use following code:

```
for j in range(6):
   model.Add(worker_shift[(j)]==0).OnlyEnforceIf([shifts[(i,j)].Not() for i in range(6) ]) 
   for i in range(6):
      model.Add(worker_shift[(j)]==i+1).OnlyEnforceIf(shifts[(i,j)])
```

It seems to work well !

The complete code is as follows：

```
model = cp_model.CpModel()
solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
shifts = {}
worker_shift={}

for i in range(6):
   worker_shift[(i)]=model.NewIntVar(0, 6, "worker_shift(%i)" % (i))
   for j in range(6):
      shifts[(i,j)] = model.NewBoolVar("shifts(%i,%i)" % (i,j))

for j in range(6): 
   model.Add(sum(shifts[(i,j)] for i in range(6))<=1)


for j in range(6):
   model.Add(worker_shift[(j)]==0).OnlyEnforceIf([shifts[(i,j)].Not() for i in range(6) ]) 
   for i in range(6):
      model.Add(worker_shift[(j)]==i+1).OnlyEnforceIf(shifts[(i,j)]) 

model.Add(worker_shift[(2)]==0)
model.Add(worker_shift[(0)]==0)
model.Add(worker_shift[(3)]==0)
model.Add(shifts[(2,1)]==1)
model.Add(shifts[(3,4)]==1)

r1= np.empty([6,6], dtype = int)
r2=np.empty([1,6], dtype = int)

status = solver.Solve(model) 
print("status:",status) 
for i in range(6):
   r2[0,i]=solver.Value(worker_shift[(i)])
   for j in range(6):
      r1[i,j]=solver.Value(shifts[(i,j)])

print(r1)    
print("----------------------")
print(r2)
```

[image]